# create automatic incrementor in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have to write this line saying
"10 Users have contributed 70 hours today"

Where the number 10 and 70 should keep incrementing by 1 every second till it reaches some threshold value and then it should again reset back to the old values and shud start incrementing

can anybody help me how to achieve this in jquery ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Incrementing the value of a variable? Reading a variable? Accessing and modifying the DOM? Creating a timer? I recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide) and the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a starting point - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mJAmX/)

```
var userStart = 10,
    hourStart = 70,
    userLimit = 15,
    hourLimit = 80;

setInterval(function() {
    var users = document.getElementById("users");
    var hours = document.getElementById("hours");

    if ( ( parseInt( users.innerHTML ) + 1 ) <= userLimit ) {
        users.innerHTML = parseInt( users.innerHTML ) + 1;
    }

    if ( ( parseInt( hours.innerHTML ) + 1 ) <= hourLimit ) {
        hours.innerHTML = parseInt( hours.innerHTML ) + 1;
    }

    if ( hours.innerHTML == hourLimit && users.innerHTML == userLimit ) {
        users.innerHTML = userStart;
        hours.innerHTML = hourStart;     
    }
}, 1000);
```